# Support for multiple paths pointing to different graphql schema

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java, spring-graphql

I have two graphql schemas that we can say one as admin and one as internal and i need to map each with a separate graphql endpoint as:-

Schema - admin.graphqls, internal.graphqls

/graphql/admin and /graphql/internal

however the exposed configuration property we have in spring-boot-starter-graphql is a string so possible only one endpoint can be configured. I'm looking for a way to map the other one too.

dependencies used - spring-boot-starter-graphql - 3.1.5

```
spring:
    graphql:
      path: /graphql/admin/
```

When using the graphql kickstart libraries there was a way to get access to AbstractGraphQlHttpServlet which we could use to register both mapping but not with this one.